# How to configure RequireJS for Dojo and KnockoutJS framework together?

Tags: knockout.js, dojo, requirejs

`<script data-main="js/main" src="/js/libs/require/require.js"></script>`here main file is not getting called......this project has also dojo framework
I am trying to assamble dojo and knockoutjs in the same project for that i am using requirejs but requirejs configuration file is not getting called...

Comment: An example would be helpful. There are too many unknown variables here, such as the layout of your filesystem.

Comment: what about an slash at the beginning of data-main attr, i.e. `'/js/main'`? Is main really there?